# ListView and SetAdapter null pointer exception

Tags: android, json, listview, adapter

I have got a problem with listview for a json parser !

(ArretsFragment.java) :

```
package activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.example.pierre.tan.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adapter.CustomListAdapter;
import app.AppController;
import model.Movie;


public class ArretsFragment extends Fragment {

// Log tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;


public ArretsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Showing progress dialog before making http request



    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = null;
                            try {
                                obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());


        }


    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_arrets, container, false);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

and i've got this (CustomListAdapter.java) :

```
package adapter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.example.pierre.tan.R;

import java.util.List;

import app.AppController;
import model.Movie;



public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    // genre
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
    genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
            genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    genre.setText(genreStr);

    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

When i try to lauch my application i've got these errors :

```
04-16 11:14:57.416  27043-27043/com.example.pierre.tan E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pierre.tan, PID: 27043
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at activity.ArretsFragment.onCreate(ArretsFragment.java:55)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

It's a little difficult process so if someone can help me it would be very nice

Comment: is your `ListView` declared in fragment_arrets.xml?

Comment: read the fragments documentation at the developer site

Comment: Maybe your problem is the listview is not declared in the xml

Comment: Yes Blackbelt it is ! Fragment arrets : " <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />"

Comment: problem is with fragment lifecicle. you trying to access to list view before create fragment view. Also you trying to find List view inside activity, but you should do it inside fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is inside:

```
listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Your activity does not contains your listView.

Add all of this to `onActivityCreated()` method

```
listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and learn Fragment [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 0):

You parse an empty array of Movies to your adapter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    // movieList is an empty array at this point.
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // ...
}
```

I guess you just have to set your adapter after you've populated the list with data from the movieReq request.

Comment: Adapters normally cannot work with `null`, but an empty ArrayList should be fine, or am I missing something.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the log shown and if you look carefully initialization in `onCreate` of `Fragment` and that too using getActivity

Comment: Clearly the worse solution... onCreate documentation reads : *Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to infalte your layout before retrieve the listview.

In a fragment, do all your treatments in the `onCreateView` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_arrets, container, false);

  listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Showing progress dialog before making http request



    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = null;
                            try {
                                obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());


        }


    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: "In a fragment, do all your treatments in the onCreateView method." => Please don't do this. It is a very bad idea to call getActivity() in onCreateView, because it might return null, so if it is used in the adapter's initialization, you might end up with another NPE on your hands...

Comment: I always did that and it worked but if you have a better solution in terms of performances or something else, i'll be glad to here it !

Comment: onCreate documentation reads : *Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point.*

Comment: I agree but where can we put the operations if it is not in the onCreateView ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)